# When using the "Present in Teams" feature in an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation, how can I start the presentation at the current slide?

Tags: office-365, microsoft-teams

I sometimes use the "Present in Teams" feature in an Office 365 PowerPoint online presentation. How can I start the presentation at the current slide, and not at the first slide of the presentation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot start the presentation at the current slide (unless it is the first slide of the presentation). Source: [Reddit](https://redd.it/10t2i0t) user [limp15000](https://www.reddit.com/user/limp15000):

> This will always start from the beginning (when you present the deck for the first time).